# download csv error in php

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I have a address column(with , and .) in my table, when i download table using php it will not coming in proper manner here is my code

my address column data is like 'Plot No: 34, Krishna Mahalaxmi Nagar, XXX, Beside XXXX XXXX, XXXXX.'

```
foreach ($stmt1 as $row) {
  if (!$flag) {
      echo implode("\t", array_keys($row)) . "\r\n";
      $flag = true;
  }
  foreach ($row as $k => $v) {
      if ($k == 'id') {
          $row[$k] = $count;
      }
      if ($k == 'previous_school') {
          $row[$k] = str_replace('/[ ,]+/', ' ', trim($v));;
      }
      if ($k == 'address') {
          $row[$k] = str_replace('/[ ,]+/', ' ', trim($v));;
      }
  }
  echo implode("\t", array_values($row)) . "\r\n";
  $count++;
}
```

[Please click link for image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yBk1C.png)

Comment: Can you explain in more detail what you mean by "not coming in proper manner"?

Comment: Please also provide a sample (2 lines) of the CSV data in question so that we can test with it.

Comment: It is still unclear what exactly you are trying to get as a result.

Comment: i added the screen shot, i think that will understand

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$row[$k] = str_replace(' ,', ' ', trim($v));
```

or

```
$row[$k] = preg_replace('/[ ,]+/', ' ', trim($v));
```